# How to Read data image in Codeigniter from database? (Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function img())

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

i'm a newbie using CodeIgniter, I want read data img from database and I try with used **img($row->img)** got this error, why do I get this error ?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function img()

This is my Controller **karyawan.php**

```
foreach ($karyawan as $row)
        {
            $this->table->add_row(++$i, $row->nik, img($row->img) , $row->nama_karyawan, $row->telepon, $this->DateToIndo($row->tgl_masuk), ($row->status_aktif == '1' ? 'Aktif' : '<span style="text-decoration:blink; color:#ff0000">Ex-Karyawan</span>'),
                                    anchor('karyawan/detail/'.$row->nik,'<img alt="Detail" src="'.base_url().'/asset/images/icons/view.png"> View').' '.
                                    anchor('karyawan/update/'.$row->nik,'<img alt="Edit" src="'.base_url().'/asset/images/icons/pencil.png"> Edit').' '.
                                    anchor('karyawan/delete/'.$row->nik,'<img alt="Delete" src="'.base_url().'/asset/images/icons/cross.png"> Delete',array('onclick'=>"return confirm('Anda yakin akan menghapus data ini?')"))                                        
                                    );
        }
        $data['table'] = $this->table->generate();
```

This is my Model **karyawan_model.php**

```
function get_allKaryawan()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->order_by('nik', 'asc');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I found that answer.

Replace this code

 `img($row->img)`

to

 `"<img src=" .base_url().$row->img.">"`

Answer (score 0):

Is because you did not defined any function like that on codeigniter. So if you are trying to view the image use this

```html
<img src="<php echo base_url('path/to/image/'.$img);?>" />
```

I hope this will help you